# How to increase speed of converting image to bitmap without lazy loading android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

In my project i have used page curl and display image to page, so when i curl that page that time the view/layout is convert to bitmap so after convert that i am not able to set image using lazy loading. so i need to first convert image to bitmap and set on ImageView for that image url to bitmap converting process is take long time if any way fast way to convert imageurl to bitmap then please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use the Picasso Library from Jake Wharton. Its a good way to load in one line your image and manage caching, transformations, download etc..

Here is the link to download the library: http://square.github.io/picasso/

All the code you need is :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://yourimage.jpg").into(yourImageView);
```

you should try it and I hope it helps you :)